# How do I redirect and pass my Google API data after handling it in my Oauth2callback handler on Google App Engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

My Oauth2Callback handler is able to access the Google API data I want - I want to know the best way to get this data to my other handler so it can use the data I've acquired.

I figure I can add it to the datastore, or also perform redirect with the data.  Is there a "best way" of doing this?  For a redirect is there a better way than adding it to query string?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a better way of doing it, I just use the oauth callback to redirect only with no data, and then on the redirect handler I access the API data.